# Show $\mathbb{Q^2}$ is not open and not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Exercise:** Show the set $ C = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x,y \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is not open and not closed ( the metric is the Euclidian metric ).

**Attempt:**  ( The question is the same as proving that in $ \mathbb{R^2} $, $\mathbb{Q^2}$ is neither open nor closed )

*not open:*  For $ (p,q) \in \mathbb{Q^2} $ let $ r>0 $, there exist $ x,y \in \mathbb{R \setminus Q} $  s.t. $ |p-x| < \frac{r}{2} $, $ |q-y| < \frac{r}{2} $, then it occurs that  $ d( (p,q) , (x,y) ) \leq d( (p,q),(x,q) ) + d( (x,q),(x,y) ) \leq | p-x | + | q - y | < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2} = r  $.
Hence, $ (x,y) \in B( (p,q),r )  $ but $ (x,y) \notin \mathbb{Q^2} $ hence $ \mathbb{Q}^2 $ is not open. Hence we can choose any $ (p,q) \in \mathbb{Q^2} $ and we're finished proving $ C $ is *not open*.

*not closed:* We'll show that $ \mathbb{R^2 \setminus Q^2 } $ is not open ( Meaning, we want to find a point in $ \mathbb{R^2 \setminus Q^2 } $ s.t. every ball around it is not in $ C $ ). **[ missing arguments for completing proof ]**

How do I proceed to prove the "*not closed*" part? I know that for every $ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} $ there exists irrationals $ z,w \in \mathbb{ R \setminus Q } $ s.t. $ (z,w) \in B( (x,y) ,r ) $, maybe this can help me?

**Edit:** I think this is the proof for the "not closed" part,
For every $ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}  $ and for every $ r>0 $, since $ \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $ \mathbb{R} $ then there exist  $ \tau = (z,w) \notin \mathbb{R^2 \setminus Q^2} $ s.t. $ \tau \in B( (x,y),r) $ hence $ B( (x,y),r) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R^2 \setminus Q^2} $.
Hence we can take any $ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2\setminus Q^2}   $ and we're finished.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\Bbb Q$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it ( haven't thought about it ) I think I know how to proceed ( i'll edit if I'll make a progress )

Comment: Ok, I added what I think is a proof for the 'not closed' part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the sequence $$(1,0), (1.4,0), (1.41,0), (1.414, 0), (1.4142,0),\dots$$

The sequence converges to $(\sqrt{2},0)$.